How do I call a function in cypress.io for E2E test automation?
I am in a QA bootcamp (Coding Temple) and I am working on an assignment where we take pseudo code and turn it into an automated test using javaScript functions in cypress. However, I just cannot get it right!! Cypress keeps saying there is no tests!! Can someone please look over my code and tell me what Im doing wrong? I have been stuck on this for over 24 hours.
const url = 'http://www.demo.applitools.com';
const validUsername = 'leilasabolic';
const validPassword = 'qaisfun202';

function launchApplication(){
    cy.visit('url');
}

function enterUsername(“validUsername”){
    cy.get('action.username').type('validUsername');
}

function enterPassword(“validPassword”){
    cy.get('action.password').type('validPassword');
}

function clickLoginButton(){
    cy.get('#query-btn').should('contain', 'Button').click();
}

function verifyLoginSuccess(){
}

or
const url = 'http://www.demo.applitools.com';
const validUsername = 'leilasabolic';
const validPassword = 'qaisfun202';

function login(validUsername, validPassword) {
    cy.get('#username').type('validUsername');
    cy.get('#password').type('validPassword');
    cy.get('#button').click();
}


You know Cypress has extremely detailed and well written documentation, right?

Have you checked docs? What have you tried?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans ....yes I know I have been scouring the documentation for 24 hours

@Hujaakbar what i tried is the code above

If you scoured it for 24 hours, then you scoured the wrong thing: that link literally shows you how to write your first test, and your code looks nothing like what that teaches you to use. Start with throwing away what you have, copying what the documentation teaches you to use, and then expand on that once you see that working.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thank you sir! Smh! I guess I’m paying a bootcamp to teach me wrong lmao FML

That's the downside of bootcamps - you get the benefit of not having to piece everything together yourself, but at the same time, you're trusting that you're being taught "the right thing", and sometimes you're just not.

The best way to get started with your test is to let Cypress set it up for you.
If you start with a clean project, install and open Cypress - npx cypress open. The Cypress wizard will automatically configure itself.
After opening the runner, you can either chose "Scaffold example specs" or "Create new spec" - which shows exactly what a working spec looks like.
cypress\e2e\spec.cy.js
describe('template spec', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('https://example.cypress.io')
  })
})

The test is the it() block which has a description and a callback. You can modify the contents to reflect your own requirements
const url = 'http://www.demo.applitools.com';
const validUsername = 'leilasabolic';
const validPassword = 'qaisfun202';

describe('testing applitools demo', () => {
  it('logs in', () => {
    cy.get('#username').type('validUsername');
    cy.get('#password').type('validPassword');
    cy.get('#button').click();
  })
})

or with a function just call it inside the it() block
const url = 'http://www.demo.applitools.com';
const validUsername = 'leilasabolic';
const validPassword = 'qaisfun202';

function login(validUsername, validPassword) {
  cy.get('#username').type('validUsername');
  cy.get('#password').type('validPassword');
  cy.get('#button').click();
}

describe('testing applitools demo', () => {
  it('logs in', () => {
    login(validUsername, validPassword)
  })
})

There's no need for custom commands for a simple set of actions such as logging in, a function is fine.
More tests
To use your function in more tests, call it in a beforeEach() block
const url = 'http://www.demo.applitools.com';
const validUsername = 'leilasabolic';
const validPassword = 'qaisfun202';

function login(validUsername, validPassword) {
  cy.get('#username').type('validUsername');
  cy.get('#password').type('validPassword');
  cy.get('#button').click();
}

describe('testing applitools demo', () => {
  it('logs in', () => {
    login(validUsername, validPassword)
  })

  context('after logging in', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      login(validUsername, validPassword)
    })

    it('tests something on the page', () => {
      ...
    })


    it('tests something else on the page', () => {
      ...
    })
  })
})


Cypress uses Mocha to executes tests. (It is built-in to Cypress, so you don't need to install it.) So, in order to have Cypress identify your functions as tests, they'll need to be in Mocha blocks - describe, context, or it. Tests that share common setup and teardown, or  are in a common area are often grouped together underneath describe or context blocks, and the individual tests are in the it blocks.
describe('My Tests', () => {
  it('Validates I can login succesfully', () => {
    launchApplication();
    enterUsername('foo');
    enterPassword('bar');
    clickLoginButton();
    verifyLoginSuccess();
  });
});

So your functions that you have written can be called within the it (or describe/context blocks).
As an aside, Cypress recommends you use Cypress Custom Commands instead of abstracting Cypress code to a vanilla JS function. (I understand that you're going through a Bootcamp, just some additional information on Cypress best practices.)
